# New tag suggestions

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I just asked [a question about Serbian street food](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17663/can-you-identify-this-serbian-street-food) and discovered we have no [street-food](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-food) tag and also no [serbian-cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serbian-cuisine) tag.

We do have [balkan-cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balkan-cuisine) which I used.

If you think the more specific Serbian cuisine tag is warranted, or perhaps Yugoslavian cuisine, please create it and add it to my question. If it turns out that the Balkan cuisine tag is already best for this question then that's also fine.

But what about street food? Is there an alternative tag I could use that covers this? Again please create it and add it to my question if you feel it would be useful for the site.

Thanks for listening (-:

Comment: I'd follow a street-food tag, but I don't know that we have enough questions yet that fall into the category (and it'd be hard to tell w/out looking through most of the questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added [serbian-cuisine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serbian-cuisine), although keep in mind that low-frequency tags are automatically pruned by the system, so it might disappear after several weeks/months if it's rarely been used.

I also added [restaurant-mimicry](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restaurant-mimicry) to your question, which I think is close enough; *restaurant* doesn't have to mean a fancy Michelin 3-star establishment, just any place that serves food commercially.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a pretty casual user here so whatever the regulars think is best is best as far as I'm concerned too.